# Why could this method defined in interface but not implemented in class be called?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Say here I have an Java interface Eat:

```
public interface Eat {
    default void eat(Meat meat) {}

    @Deprecated
    default void eat(Meat meat, Mood mood) {}
}
```

And I have an abstract class implements only one method in the interface:

```
public abstract class DogBase implements Eat {
    @Override
    public void eat(Meat meat) {}
}
```

And I have a class extends the abstract class:

```
public class Dog extends DogBase {

}
```

Then I found that in the unit test for Dog class, the deprecated method:

```
@Deprecated
default void eat(Meat meat, Mood mood) {}
```

defined in the interface Eat can be called by an object of Dog class.

Why is this possible? In my understanding, the abstract class DogBase only implements the non-deprecated method defined in the interface so that class Dog should not have the deprecated method.

Comment: The method is `@default` and so it is implemented, whether deprecated or not. Deprecated methods *are* inherited

Comment: All the `@deprecated` annotation does is generate a compiler warning.